# PHP changing date format

Tags: php

I have created this PHP function that changes the format of a date in PHP:

```
if(!function_exists("ChangeDateFormat")) {
    function ChangeDateFormat($date = '', $format = '') {
        if($date == '' or $date == '0000-00-00' or $date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            return '-';
        } else {
            return date($format, strtotime($date));
        }
    }
}
```

this code:

```
ChangeDateFormat('12/01/2015', 'Y-m-d')
```

should change the date into format:

```
2015-01-12
```

but instead its changing to:

```
2015-12-01
```

Comment: [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) - dates with a `/` separator are treated as US format; dates with a `-` are treated as European format.... if you're working with an ambiguous format, then you need to specify what you mean..... [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Just to be sure of what you're trying to do, are you looking for 12 January or 1 December ?

Comment: It does exactly what it needs to do.

Comment: you got to set your locale according to the results you expect.
You server does not know whether your cultural background meant 12-january or 1st-december and used what it thinks you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because PHP sees date formats with slashes as 'american'.. ..so `12/01/2015` is December 1st.

Add this to your function:

```
$date = str_replace('/','-',$date);
```

and dates will be seen as 'english'.